# SpringBoot multiple configurations

Tags: maven, spring-boot, dependencies, spring-boot-configuration

I have following structure (maven)

Parent:

- Common (module)
- Server (module)
- Batch (module)

---

1. All (Batch, Server) sees Common
2. Batch sees Server (and Common transitively: Batch -> Server -> Common)

For IntegrationTests to loading an ApplicationContext (spring context is needed) i need something like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
```

Application.class is main SpringBoot class (in Common module)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.domain")
@EnableJpaRepositories("pl.domain.repository")
@EntityScan("pl.domain.model")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Now i want have other @Configuration for Batch module:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Service1 service1() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public Service2 service2() {
        ...
    }

}
```

In above config i can't import BatchConfiguration in Application.

How initialize beans: service1, service2?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also what do you mean by you cant import BatchConfiguration in Application?

Comment: Application is in the Common module, BatchConfiguration is in the Batch module. So 'Common' module don't sees 'Batch' module (impossible by dependency management in maven config).